# Clear values from the cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do I clear contents from the UITableView cell.detailTextLabel.text? Once user taps clear left bar button on the top I want all the answers to be cleared?

Below is my code. Not sure if this is the correct way.

```
-(void)ClearBtn:(id)sender {    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"test";
    //NSLog(@"cell %@", cell.detailTextLabel.text);
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to delete the cell, you can add following code to the delegate of the table

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
int flag = 0;

UIButton *recipient = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
oldCell.textLabel.text = @"";
}
```

And in case you want to delete all the content you can just empty you dataSource variable and reload the table simply.

Hope t works for you!!